# How to create custom file path for recordings base?

Tags: android, android-room, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying to save my recordings to the Room database and this is almost fine, but I don't know how to create my own file path to save more than just one file. I've tried so far just add date and my own name of the file at end of file, but it didn't work. If I save standard path and then press play it works, but I can save just one file (same path). If I trying to create own path I have info in logs: Log.e(TAG, "prepare() failed");

Setup:

```
 private void setupMediaRecorder() {
    filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "myRecording.3gpp";
    File file = new File(filePath);
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file);
}
```

Save:

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = String.valueOf(nameEditText.getText());
            Recording recording = new Recording(name, filePath, length, currentDate);
            mainViewModel.insertRecording(recording);
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Play:

```
private void play() {

    playing = true;

    playbackButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_true_24dp);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Playing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, filePath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }
}
```

SOLUTION:

I found solution of my problem. Problem was in two signs: ":" for the time and "/" for the date.  These signs are using to create path of the file and media player had problem with find proper path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the current date and time, then use that as the file name.

```
private void setupMediaRecorder() { 
    filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + getDateAndTime()+".3gpp"; 
    File file = new File(filePath);
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file);        
}

private String getDateAndTime(){
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") DateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    String date=dfDate.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") DateFormat dfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
    String time = dfTime.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    return date + "-" + time;
}
```

By doing this, you will always use a different name for your file.

Comment: Your concept seems to be fine, but I have that error after trying to save: E/MediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state: 4

Comment: That's not related to this question. Mediarecorder is not happy about some parameters that was passed to it. Please accept  this question and ask another question.

Comment: Still same. Sorry for late answer.

Comment: When exactly does this error occur and did you provide permissions?

Comment: When I'm trying to save recording. I set just normal string to the path and then saving works, but I can't play recorded file. Yes, permissions are provided.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then the problem is how you declare and use `filePath`

Comment: Still same. I'll check the filePath soon. Too busy day, sorry. I'll give you know.

Comment: I'm stuck. I tried few paths of saving and still same. The problem is in path of the files, but I still can't find solution. In File Explorer in emulator I found the folder with files, but... there are only files with changed path. Standard path is also addressed to the same place and there is no files. So strange.

Comment: You were very close. The problem was in these two signs ":" and "/" in formats. Without them is fine. Thank you for help.